# Magento 2 - How do I track login/register/subscribe with JavaScript?

Tags: magento2, javascript, login, register, ecommerce-tracking

In Magento 2 I need to invoke some JS tracking when the following things happen:

- customer logs into site
- customer registers account
- newsletter subscribe success
- customer updates account details
- order success

Apart from order success which has an actual page to trigger the JavaScript, I'm not sure on the best way to track the other events seeing as their success seems to be fully handled by PHP only.

Regarding the login/register requirement I have seen that there's a JS handler in `module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/action/login.js` which has this:

```
action.registerLoginCallback = function(callback) {
        callbacks.push(callback);
    };
```

But I'm not sure how this can be hooked into in my module. Are there any resources that could help here? I'm just looking for suggestions on the best practice way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to use cookies due to how slow the local storage was to load so I have answered my question with this blog post: https://adammoss.co.uk/magentofox/private-data-tracking-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion.

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<block name="customer.customer.data"
               class="Magento\Customer\Block\CustomerData"
               template="Magento_Customer::js/customer-data.phtml"/>
```

Magento will load `js/customer-data.phtml` on every page. The js file: `js/customer-data.js` is also loaded.

We need add our custom js via phtml on every page with `after.body.start`

app/code/Vendor/Tracking/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Vendor\Tracking\Block\Js"
                   name="tracking" as="tracking" template="js.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create the our tracking js and put it in `js.phtml` template.

We can check the data with: `$(document).on('submit', function() {});` and `$(document).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, xhr, settings) {})`. See more: `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer‌​-data.js`.

Comment: That's a good idea but I'm not sure how I'd be able to access the customer login data / newsletter subscriber data from these files?

Comment: Not test yet. However, I think we can get the data with `$(document).on('submit', function() {});` in the custom js, for example.

Comment: Or, we can use `$(document).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, xhr, settings) {})`. You should take a look: `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js`